# Cannot resolve symbols yet library is imported

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm using libGDX and I've cloned a project down from a repo I pushed too earlier. I've set the project up and imported it to Intellij IDEA but it's giving me import errors. I can actually [navigate to the classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziayK.png) that are giving me an error but the IDE doesn't seem to recognise them.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What symbols can't it resolve?

Comment: See the symbols highlighted in red? All those. I was specifically pointing out ExtendViewport which I have selected on the left and highlighted in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over the unused import Intellij IDEA pops up a little red bulb which allows you to add the library to the classpath. Finding that fixed it.